# ETC vs ETH how do I know the difference?

Tags: ethereum

How do I know if Ethereum is ETH or ETC, when the exchange just offers "Ethereum"

Comment: can you not understand on the basis of rates? are they same / different?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum is usually ETH, Ethereum Classic is ETC.